# Запуск скрипта по времени

Tags: python, telebot

Возможно ли сделать запуск скрипта каждые 5 минут, при этом, должны работать другие функции во время ожидания. У меня есть телеграмм бот на основе pytelegrambotapi, мне нужно запустить определенную функцию автоматически без каких-либо команд от пользователя каждые 5 минут. Скрипт выполняется примерно секунд за 5 весь, он должен выполниться и уйти в режим ожидания на 4 минуты 55 секунд, а в это время, пользователь может запросить выполнение от бота какой-либо другой задачи

```
def main_start():
    print('main_start')
    schedule.every(5).minutes.do(cycle_wbot)
    # schedule.every().minute.at(':28').do(cycle_wbot)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_start()
```

вот так не работает

Comment: выполнение по расписанию - планировщик задач для windows, Cron - Linux

Comment: стоит все на Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Попробуйте в отдельном потоке цикл обработки запускать. Также если используете aiogram, то я видел асинхронные варианты schedule, по идее их не так сложно будет друг с другом подружить.

Answer (score 0):

Пошел по наименее затратному пути для меня, предложенному @insolor, создал дополнительный скрипт, который запускаю параллельно на сервере с помощью systemd.

@Zeinan, не пробовал Ваш вариант, так как не было времени